# Not able to navigate in Skobler Offline Mode iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps, objective-c-category, skobbler-maps

I am using SKMaps and SDKTools provided by Skobbler to render maps, calculate and navigate routes.

By referring to their Demo Project, I am able to download map package for offline usage. However I am not able to navigate or render the downloaded package.

Before downloading map package this is what I do : -

```
[SKMapsService sharedInstance].connectivityMode = SKConnectivityModeOnline;
```

Once downloading of map package is finished , here is what I do : -

```
[[SKMapsService sharedInstance].packagesManager addOfflineMapPackageNamed:code inContainingFolderPath:path];
```

But it does not calculate the route .

Any help?

Comment: Is it that every-time a map package is downloaded, it needs to be put in PreInstalled Maps folder manually (by copy/paste) in order to use the offline map feature?

Comment: Are you sure your package is downloaded? What results are your expecting and what do you actually see?

Comment: @Koen: - I am expecting that when my map package is downloaded, I should be able to navigate for downloaded region only. What actually happening is that no route is calculated and routeCalculationFailed method is trigerred. I doubt that is due to the connectionMode set to Offline but not sure.